# Xtemplate if conditions in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, if-statement, sencha-touch

I have the following Xtemplate code:

```
('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<div class="moreArrow"></div>',
    '<div class="img"><img src="http://localhost/WL2/assets/rest/{image}"/></div>',                       
    '<div class="meta">',
    '<h3>{merchName}</h3>',
    '<div class="actions">',
        '<button class="seen{[values.seen ? " selected" : ""]}">{action}</button>',
        '{% if (values.seen) { %}',
            '<button class="thumb up{[values.like ? " selected" : ""]}"><b></b></button>',
            '<button class="thumb down{[values.dislike ? "selected" : ""]}"><b></b>  </button>',
        '{% } else { %}',
            '<button class="want{[values.wantToSee ? "selected" : ""]}">Want to Go There</button>',
        '{% } %}',
        '</div>',
    '</div>'
)
```

My problem is that the if condition in the part `{% if (values.seen) { %}` is not working, that is when the button is clicked, it should show two buttons of dislike and like. What is wrong with my code that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might not be working because you are not comparing it with anything.

BTW, here are few examples to understand how to use **if** condition:

Using comparison operators:

```
<tpl if="totalDiscount &gt; 0">
```

Using 'AND' operator

```
<tpl if="active == true && available == true">
```

Using XTemplates variables:

```
'{% if (xindex % 2 === 1) { %}' +
    '<div>Odd Row</div>' +
'{% } %}'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you're using XTemplate correctly. Check out [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) page and try to replace your conditions with `<tpl if>` tag