# Rendering conditional statement on grid templatecolumn [ExtJS 4.2.1]

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have been successfully rendering conditional statement on normal grid column

```
{
        header: '&nbsp',
        dataIndex: 'status_b2',
        menuDisabled: true,
        flex: 1,
        sortable: false,
        renderer : function(value, meta) {
            var status = value.split("<br/>")[0];

            if (status == "Unset Price"){
                meta.style = "background-color:pink;";
            }
            else if (status == "Available"){
                meta.style = "background-color:green;";
            }else if (status == "Booked Unpaid"){
                meta.style = "background-color:yellow;";
            }else if (status == "Booked Paid"){
                meta.style = "background-color:orange;";
            }else if (status == "Checked In"){
                meta.style = "background-color:red;";
            }else if (status == "Checked Out"){
                meta.style = "background-color:purple;";
            }
            return value;
}
```

My question is how to render with conditional logic on templatecolumn grid? If the room_status == "Dirty", I want to add background-color as red.

```
{
            text: 'Room List',
            xtype: 'templatecolumn',
            tpl: 'ROOM {room_number} <br/> {room_type_name} <br/> {bed_type} | {room_status}',
            menuDisabled: true,
            flex: 1,
            sortable: false
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these links [sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127059-XTemplate-Conditional-Processing) and [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057703/xtemplate-if-conditions-in-sencha-touch)

We can have some inline functions and call them. Follow this [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?108242-How-can-I-run-inline-functions-in-an-XTemplate). Implement your logic inside these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I too am used to using renderers to add styles to cells to give them highlighting. Effectively, templatecolumn already has a renderer that is applied by default, and it works by basically returning the template applied to the record. So if you want to use your own renderer, you could either replicate the two lines of code from the defaultRenderer, or just call the column's defaultRenderer directly:

```
function customRenderer(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view)
{
  if (record.get('severity') == 'critical')
  {
    metaData.tdCls += ' redHighlight';
  }
  return view.panel.columns[colIndex].defaultRenderer(value, metaData, record);
};
```